# How do I parse a string into "header object"?

Tags: javascript, string-parsing

I have a String in Javascript. It looks somewhat like this:

```
' "foo": "" , /n "bar": "" '
```

I need it so I can do a request for a API, and the request is made like this:

```
$http
  .post(urlToAPI, {
    "foo": "",
    "bar": ""
  })
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log("yay")
  })
```

As you can see, as a parameter, I'm giving the post method a structure that contains both foo and bar. The problem is that I can't pass my own string in there, because I need to Parse it before.

So, basically, I need this

```
' "foo": "" , /n "bar": "" '
```

To become this:

```
"foo": "", "bar": ""
```

I tried to use `JSON.parse()`, but it won't work, since it's not a JSON object. 
I also tried some CSV converters, but it seems like that isn't a CSV either. I don't even know the name of that kind of structure, so I've been struggling a bit on how to parse it.

Do you have any clue?

Comment: " It looks somewhat like this", is that exactly what it looks like?

Comment: `var str = ' "foo": "" , /n "bar": "" ';  JSON.parse(('{' + str + '}').replace(' /n', ''));`

Comment: @phuzi hahah, well... The actual string has real values and it's pretty big XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really mean /n and not \n

```
var str = ' "foo": "" , /n "bar": "" ';
JSON.parse(('{' + str + '}').replace(' /n', ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of massaging you can format the string properly and put its values into an object. Then just pass the whole object into your AJAX call:

```
.post(urlToAPI, obj)
```

```js
let str = ' "foo": "" , /n "bar": "" ';
const arr = str.trim().replace("/n","").split("\"").join("").split(",");
const obj = {};
arr.forEach((el, idx) => {
  let arr2 = el.split(":");
  obj[arr2[0].trim()] = arr2[1].trim(); 
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume the `/n` is actually a `\n`  (newline). If that is the case, you can parse your string as json taking advantage of the `eval` function:

```
var input=' "foo": "" , \n "bar": "" ';
var serial="json={"+input+"}";
var json=eval(serial);
// Now you can access json.foo and json.bar
```

Comment: I don't think recommending `eval` when not needed is a good idea.

Comment: @Molda  Why not? Security reasons?

Comment: @LittleSanti [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)

Comment: Indeed, if you are concerned about security, you should get rid of javascript in the first place. But I agree: Invoking `eval` should be done carefully.